# Is there a resource on the web that would help me build a clean android studio app is correct implementation versions?

Tags: android, compilation

I've been working with Android Studio only for a short time and it's giving me a lot of grief. I have a project that (so far) requires

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"

    // added 8/29
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.3.1"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    // added
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0'

    // hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    implementation 'androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.0.0'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")

    // datastore
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"
```

where

```
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta03'
        hilt_version = '2.40'
        kotlin_version = '1.5.30' //'1.4.32'
```

I've spent several hours trying to find a good set that does result in build warnings because of conflicting JDK version reported as well as messages saying I have to build using API 32 or 33 when I really want API 29. If I can build at 33 but still have minSDK of 29, that would work too.

I think a web tool where I could list the libraries and the API and it would give me the version numbers of the libraries, that would solve my problem.

Any suggestions? BTW - I'm using the Chipmunk.

Comment: "I have to build using API 32 or 33 when I really want API 29" -- there is no reason to use a `compileSdkVersion` of `29` in 2022 for new projects. "If I can build at 33 but still have minSDK of 29, that would work too" -- if by "build at 33" you mean `compileSdkVersion` of `33`, that is fine. `compileSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` are independent.

Comment: To be clear, if the compileSdkVersion is set at 33 (and the targetSdk is set to what I've tested it on - might be lower?), setting the minSdk to get 29 would allow it to run on Android 10 but I might have to do some "conditional" code. So minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion

Comment: That all sounds correct. The Android SDK has a bunch of `...Compat` classes that can help you avoid the manual conditional code.

Comment: I guess you are proposing in general is that you should not only update the compileSdkVersion but also the implementation versions to the latest stable release.